# cross-signed end-entity certificates: usage in apache/openssl/gnutls

Tags: tls, openssl, apache, x.509

A previous question, [What is the use of cross signing certificates in X.509?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14043/what-is-the-use-of-cross-signing-certificates-in-x-509) described cross-signed certificates well.

I have a situation where the clients trust CA1 xor CA2, and both need to reach a single service. Logically, this means I need two end-entity certificates for the same hostname. From a single SSL key, I generated a single CSR and submitted to both CAs, and gotten the two separate end-entity certificates.

I configured Apache to serve both certificates together and all relevant intermediates in the chain.

What's gotten me stumped is the ability to get Apache mod_ssl crashes hard with `[Tue Nov 25 15:28:35 2014] [error] Init: Multiple RSA server certificates not allowed'`

OpenSSL's `s_server` reads multiple `-cert`, `-dcert` arguments, takes the first RSA certificate in the last argument.

Using GnuTLS either via mod_gnutls or directly, either takes just the last certificate or claims `The provided X.509 certificate list is not sorted (in subject to issuer order)`

I think, reading RFC4158, what I'm trying to do should be valid. Where have I gone wrong? Why does cross-signing only seem to be valid among intermediate and root certificates?

There is no way ahead of time to differentiate between the clients, so I can't cheat and run different vhosts on different IPs (the clients share DNS). I don't have control over getting both CAs into the clients either. The only working work-around I have so far is to push each group of clients to a unique hostname out-of-band.

Comment: Could you cite the place in RFC4158 you mean?

Comment: RFC4158: Figure 8, if the EE was in place of B, because B->A and B->C exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl s_server -cert -dcert` is only useful if the certs (and matching keys `-key -dkey`) are *different algorithms*. Then it will use e.g. the RSA key&cert for plain-RSA or DHE-RSA key exchange but the DSS key&cert for DHE-DSS. And similarly for ECDSA and ECDHE-ECDSA now that ECC is supported (since 1.0.0 except for RedHat).

Apache appears to be the same. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile says

> This directive can be used multiple times (referencing different filenames) to support multiple algorithms for server authentication - typically RSA, DSA, and ECC. ...

and #sslcertificatekeyfile says

> The directive can be used multiple times (referencing different filenames) to support multiple algorithms for server authentication. For each SSLCertificateKeyFile directive, there must be a matching SSLCertificateFile directive.

This would only help if you can get your clients to enable/disable different keyexchanges based on which CA they want you to use, which is probably harder and more confusing than using different hostnames.

There actually is a standard extension defined for [TLS1.0 by 3546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546#section-3.4) [TLS1.1 by 4366](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4366#section-3.4) [TLS1.2 by 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-6) for the client to identify which CAs it trusts, and would like the server to use. But most extensions are optional and as far as I have seen no browser (or client at all) implements this one.

Comment: Yes, that trusted_ca_keys extension does look like it would solve the problem; but sadly it seems that neither of these sets of clients nor OpenSSL support it.

Answer (score 2):

I read the TLS1.2 spec to allow **ONLY ONE CHAIN** to be sent.:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-48

```
certificate_list
      This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
      certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
      certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.
```

Comment: Isn't this already ignored by instances where you have an intermediate CA certified by multiple roots? Per RFC4158, figure 8.

Comment: @robbat2: Well, you can have several paths. (That start with the same end-entity-certificate but end with different root CAs.) But AFAIK you only get to *SEND* one of them when establishing TLS/SSL.