# Same domain, same local network, different certificate chain

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority, openssl, pem

I was doing some security checks in some devices in my local network and I noticed that I obtain two different certificate chains for the same domain ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) from two different devices (smartphone and desktop pc, again both connected to same network).

Chain in desktop:

```
################
CERT 1
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            26:3e:d1:82:f7:fb:23:0e:0a:d3:dd:ae:a3:df:7d:88
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 12 08:17:00 2022 GMT
            Not After : Dec  5 08:16:59 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = *.google.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:e0:98:18:28:6a:db:11:bf:da:c9:52:fb:49:c6:
                    b7:67:2c:88:32:8d:13:c7:d3:6e:7d:41:64:09:0a:
                    22:b3:be:df:00:da:b9:32:a7:5b:29:ef:52:f9:c7:
                    c7:3b:65:36:df:3a:87:b6:17:6a:04:5d:0a:70:b2:
                    b0:c3:65:b7:d2
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                5E:84:F1:20:21:1F:26:D1:E7:10:D5:B6:6E:81:9E:6A:00:0E:98:4A
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:8A:74:7F:AF:85:CD:EE:95:CD:3D:9C:D0:E2:46:14:F3:71:35:1D:27

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1c3
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.goog/repo/certs/gts1c3.der

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.bdn.dev, DNS:*.origin-test.bdn.dev, DNS:*.cloud.google.com, DNS:*.crowdsource.google.com, DNS:*.datacompute.google.com, DNS:*.google.ca, DNS:*.google.cl, DNS:*.google.co.in, DNS:*.google.co.jp, DNS:*.google.co.uk, DNS:*.google.com.ar, DNS:*.google.com.au, DNS:*.google.com.br, DNS:*.google.com.co, DNS:*.google.com.mx, DNS:*.google.com.tr, DNS:*.google.com.vn, DNS:*.google.de, DNS:*.google.es, DNS:*.google.fr, DNS:*.google.hu, DNS:*.google.it, DNS:*.google.nl, DNS:*.google.pl, DNS:*.google.pt, DNS:*.googleadapis.com, DNS:*.googleapis.cn, DNS:*.googlevideo.com, DNS:*.gstatic.cn, DNS:*.gstatic-cn.com, DNS:googlecnapps.cn, DNS:*.googlecnapps.cn, DNS:googleapps-cn.com, DNS:*.googleapps-cn.com, DNS:gkecnapps.cn, DNS:*.gkecnapps.cn, DNS:googledownloads.cn, DNS:*.googledownloads.cn, DNS:recaptcha.net.cn, DNS:*.recaptcha.net.cn, DNS:recaptcha-cn.net, DNS:*.recaptcha-cn.net, DNS:widevine.cn, DNS:*.widevine.cn, DNS:ampproject.org.cn, DNS:*.ampproject.org.cn, DNS:ampproject.net.cn, DNS:*.ampproject.net.cn, DNS:google-analytics-cn.com, DNS:*.google-analytics-cn.com, DNS:googleadservices-cn.com, DNS:*.googleadservices-cn.com, DNS:googlevads-cn.com, DNS:*.googlevads-cn.com, DNS:googleapis-cn.com, DNS:*.googleapis-cn.com, DNS:googleoptimize-cn.com, DNS:*.googleoptimize-cn.com, DNS:doubleclick-cn.net, DNS:*.doubleclick-cn.net, DNS:*.fls.doubleclick-cn.net, DNS:*.g.doubleclick-cn.net, DNS:doubleclick.cn, DNS:*.doubleclick.cn, DNS:*.fls.doubleclick.cn, DNS:*.g.doubleclick.cn, DNS:dartsearch-cn.net, DNS:*.dartsearch-cn.net, DNS:googletraveladservices-cn.com, DNS:*.googletraveladservices-cn.com, DNS:googletagservices-cn.com, DNS:*.googletagservices-cn.com, DNS:googletagmanager-cn.com, DNS:*.googletagmanager-cn.com, DNS:googlesyndication-cn.com, DNS:*.googlesyndication-cn.com, DNS:*.safeframe.googlesyndication-cn.com, DNS:app-measurement-cn.com, DNS:*.app-measurement-cn.com, DNS:gvt1-cn.com, DNS:*.gvt1-cn.com, DNS:gvt2-cn.com, DNS:*.gvt2-cn.com, DNS:2mdn-cn.net, DNS:*.2mdn-cn.net, DNS:googleflights-cn.net, DNS:*.googleflights-cn.net, DNS:admob-cn.com, DNS:*.admob-cn.com, DNS:*.gstatic.com, DNS:*.metric.gstatic.com, DNS:*.gvt1.com, DNS:*.gcpcdn.gvt1.com, DNS:*.gvt2.com, DNS:*.gcp.gvt2.com, DNS:*.url.google.com, DNS:*.youtube-nocookie.com, DNS:*.ytimg.com, DNS:android.com, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.flash.android.com, DNS:g.cn, DNS:*.g.cn, DNS:g.co, DNS:*.g.co, DNS:goo.gl, DNS:www.goo.gl, DNS:google-analytics.com, DNS:*.google-analytics.com, DNS:google.com, DNS:googlecommerce.com, DNS:*.googlecommerce.com, DNS:ggpht.cn, DNS:*.ggpht.cn, DNS:urchin.com, DNS:*.urchin.com, DNS:youtu.be, DNS:youtube.com, DNS:*.youtube.com, DNS:youtubeeducation.com, DNS:*.youtubeeducation.com, DNS:youtubekids.com, DNS:*.youtubekids.com, DNS:yt.be, DNS:*.yt.be, DNS:android.clients.google.com, DNS:developer.android.google.cn, DNS:developers.android.google.cn, DNS:source.android.google.cn
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crls.pki.goog/gts1c3/QOvJ0N1sT2A.crl

            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 51:A3:B0:F5:FD:01:79:9C:56:6D:B8:37:78:8F:0C:A4:
                                7A:CC:1B:27:CB:F7:9E:88:42:9A:0D:FE:D4:8B:05:E5
                    Timestamp : Sep 12 09:17:05.861 2022 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:20:44:24:D8:45:00:5F:73:39:FF:3D:50:DB:
                                C2:62:BA:ED:8E:3E:85:2C:28:1B:A0:6F:EF:BF:05:FB:
                                EF:C3:26:6A:02:21:00:AE:2D:F6:27:29:C6:39:9D:E6:
                                7A:18:AD:FB:2A:6E:16:CA:92:00:BF:E5:4B:55:49:28:
                                DE:EF:04:E1:D5:F5:85
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 46:A5:55:EB:75:FA:91:20:30:B5:A2:89:69:F4:F3:7D:
                                11:2C:41:74:BE:FD:49:B8:85:AB:F2:FC:70:FE:6D:47
                    Timestamp : Sep 12 09:17:05.880 2022 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:8A:79:E6:59:A8:A3:1B:2F:43:34:75:
                                A0:5B:86:2B:10:96:DB:40:A3:7B:05:E0:52:74:C0:CB:
                                56:3C:25:A0:D8:02:20:23:B7:1F:AB:A5:C8:DC:65:AB:
                                C5:1C:BA:03:69:CC:1B:0E:0C:63:03:E2:89:E5:01:AF:
                                16:8B:6C:E4:C0:EC:9F
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         47:56:21:93:21:a1:02:82:ec:3c:4c:82:81:bb:20:83:bc:41:
         e3:05:36:c1:27:75:de:d8:df:89:3e:07:45:c8:c6:64:a7:88:
         64:16:78:35:b8:d8:07:fc:c8:b5:16:7a:32:42:87:5d:42:82:
         91:2c:05:25:05:47:8e:d2:16:45:b6:24:30:23:19:47:3d:f2:
         24:0c:de:ad:3e:66:cc:38:83:62:c1:5a:d1:06:80:8a:9f:68:
         01:95:1c:db:2e:39:24:85:35:d1:f6:f2:68:b8:a2:8e:ca:c3:
         a7:36:34:ae:c9:93:22:95:b7:79:e1:64:e0:b2:76:ec:1d:bd:
         e8:00:8c:6e:61:38:cf:98:77:0c:f6:20:48:d9:33:16:db:e2:
         11:d2:41:5a:f3:3d:91:2b:2e:ca:c8:21:74:40:c2:7a:2e:2c:
         3a:cf:7d:22:4a:66:66:6f:05:bc:18:2d:47:11:51:a3:ab:44:
         76:9a:44:8e:c7:04:1c:5b:50:2f:9b:a0:3a:90:dc:e0:40:d8:
         f1:9d:00:13:01:b3:fe:d9:6d:f0:43:db:0d:0f:5f:e6:6a:89:
         e7:f8:9a:fb:e5:75:f9:89:27:25:b3:48:08:fa:ac:80:38:a8:
         c9:1f:32:fe:fa:d1:cb:01:bc:e8:58:8f:68:83:14:90:ac:c8:
         95:93:52:17
...

################
CERT 2
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            02:03:bc:53:59:6b:34:c7:18:f5:01:50:66
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 13 00:00:42 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep 30 00:00:42 2027 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:f5:88:df:e7:62:8c:1e:37:f8:37:42:90:7f:6c:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                8A:74:7F:AF:85:CD:EE:95:CD:3D:9C:D0:E2:46:14:F3:71:35:1D:27
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:E4:AF:2B:26:71:1A:2B:48:27:85:2F:52:66:2C:EF:F0:89:13:71:3E

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.pki.goog/gtsr1
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.goog/repo/certs/gtsr1.der

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.pki.goog/gtsr1/gtsr1.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3
                  CPS: https://pki.goog/repository/
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         89:7d:ac:20:5c:0c:3c:be:9a:a8:57:95:1b:b4:ae:fa:ab:a5:
         72:71:b4:36:95:fd:df:40:11:03:4c:c2:46:14:bb:14:24:ab:
         f0:50:71:22:db:ad:c4:6e:7f:cf:f1:6a:6f:c8:83:1b:d8:ce:
         89:5f:87:6c:87:b8:a9:0c:a3:9b:a1:62:94:93:95:df:5b:ae:
         66:19:0b:02:96:9e:fc:b5:e7:10:69:3e:7a:cb:46:49:5f:46:
         e1:41:b1:d7:98:4d:65:34:00:80:1a:3f:4f:9f:6c:7f:49:00:
         81:53:41:a4:92:21:82:82:1a:f1:a3:44:5b:2a:50:12:13:4d:
         c1:53:36:f3:42:08:af:54:fa:8e:77:53:1b:64:38:27:17:09:
         bd:58:c9:1b:7c:39:2d:5b:f3:ce:d4:ed:97:db:14:03:bf:09:
         53:24:1f:c2:0c:04:79:98:26:f2:61:f1:53:52:fd:42:8c:1b:
         66:2b:3f:15:a1:bb:ff:f6:9b:e3:81:9a:01:06:71:89:35:28:
         24:dd:e1:bd:eb:19:2d:e1:48:cb:3d:59:83:51:b4:74:c6:9d:
         7c:c6:b1:86:5b:af:cc:34:c4:d3:cc:d4:81:11:95:00:a1:f4:
         12:22:01:fa:b4:83:71:af:8c:b7:8c:73:24:ac:37:53:c2:00:
         90:3f:11:fe:5c:ed:36:94:10:3b:bd:29:ae:e2:c7:3a:62:3b:
         6c:63:d9:80:bf:59:71:ac:63:27:b9:4c:17:a0:da:f6:73:15:
         bf:2a:de:8f:f3:a5:6c:32:81:33:03:d0:86:51:71:99:34:ba:
         93:8d:5d:b5:51:58:f7:b2:93:e8:01:f6:59:be:71:9b:fd:4d:
         28:ce:cf:6d:c7:16:dc:f7:d1:d6:46:9b:a7:ca:6b:e9:77:0f:
         fd:a0:b6:1b:23:83:1d:10:1a:d9:09:00:84:e0:44:d3:a2:75:
         23:b3:34:86:f6:20:b0:a4:5e:10:1d:e0:52:46:00:9d:b1:0f:
         1f:21:70:51:f5:9a:dd:06:fc:55:f4:2b:0e:33:77:c3:4b:42:
         c2:f1:77:13:fc:73:80:94:eb:1f:bb:37:3f:ce:02:2a:66:b0:
         73:1d:32:a5:32:6c:32:b0:8e:e0:c4:23:ff:5b:7d:4d:65:70:
         ac:2b:9b:3d:ce:db:e0:6d:8e:32:80:be:96:9f:92:63:bc:97:
         bb:5d:b9:f4:e1:71:5e:2a:e4:ef:03:22:b1:8a:65:3a:8f:c0:
         93:65:d4:85:cd:0f:0f:5b:83:59:16:47:16:2d:9c:24:3a:c8:
         80:a6:26:14:85:9b:f6:37:9b:ac:6f:f9:c5:c3:06:51:f3:e2:
         7f:c5:b1:10:ba:51:f4:dd
...

################
CERT 3
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            77:bd:0d:6c:db:36:f9:1a:ea:21:0f:c4:f0:58:d3:0d
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 19 00:00:42 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jan 28 00:00:42 2028 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b6:11:02:8b:1e:e3:a1:77:9b:3b:dc:bf:94:3e:
                    ...
                   
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E4:AF:2B:26:71:1A:2B:48:27:85:2F:52:66:2C:EF:F0:89:13:71:3E
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:60:7B:66:1A:45:0D:97:CA:89:50:2F:7D:04:CD:34:A8:FF:FC:FD:4B

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.pki.goog/gsr1
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.goog/gsr1/gsr1.crt

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.pki.goog/gsr1/gsr1.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3.2
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3.3

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         34:a4:1e:b1:28:a3:d0:b4:76:17:a6:31:7a:21:e9:d1:52:3e:
         c8:db:74:16:41:88:b8:3d:35:1d:ed:e4:ff:93:e1:5c:5f:ab:
         bb:ea:7c:cf:db:e4:0d:d1:8b:57:f2:26:6f:5b:be:17:46:68:
         94:37:6f:6b:7a:c8:c0:18:37:fa:25:51:ac:ec:68:bf:b2:c8:
         49:fd:5a:9a:ca:01:23:ac:84:80:2b:02:8c:99:97:eb:49:6a:
         8c:75:d7:c7:de:b2:c9:97:9f:58:48:57:0e:35:a1:e4:1a:d6:
         fd:6f:83:81:6f:ef:8c:cf:97:af:c0:85:2a:f0:f5:4e:69:09:
         91:2d:e1:68:b8:c1:2b:73:e9:d4:d9:fc:22:c0:37:1f:0b:66:
         1d:49:ed:02:55:8f:67:e1:32:d7:d3:26:bf:70:e3:3d:f4:67:
         6d:3d:7c:e5:34:88:e3:32:fa:a7:6e:06:6a:6f:bd:8b:91:ee:
         16:4b:e8:3b:a9:b3:37:e7:c3:44:a4:7e:d8:6c:d7:c7:46:f5:
         92:9b:e7:d5:21:be:66:92:19:94:55:6c:d4:29:b2:0d:c1:66:
         5b:e2:77:49:48:28:ed:9d:d7:1a:33:72:53:b3:82:35:cf:62:
         8b:c9:24:8b:a5:b7:39:0c:bb:7e:2a:41:bf:52:cf:fc:a2:96:
         b6:c2:82:3f
...

################
CERT 4
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            04:00:00:00:00:01:15:4b:5a:c3:94
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  1 12:00:00 1998 GMT
            Not After : Jan 28 12:00:00 2028 GMT
        Subject: C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:da:0e:e6:99:8d:ce:a3:e3:4f:8a:7e:fb:f1:8b:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                60:7B:66:1A:45:0D:97:CA:89:50:2F:7D:04:CD:34:A8:FF:FC:FD:4B
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         d6:73:e7:7c:4f:76:d0:8d:bf:ec:ba:a2:be:34:c5:28:32:b5:
         7c:fc:6c:9c:2c:2b:bd:09:9e:53:bf:6b:5e:aa:11:48:b6:e5:
         08:a3:b3:ca:3d:61:4d:d3:46:09:b3:3e:c3:a0:e3:63:55:1b:
         f2:ba:ef:ad:39:e1:43:b9:38:a3:e6:2f:8a:26:3b:ef:a0:50:
         56:f9:c6:0a:fd:38:cd:c4:0b:70:51:94:97:98:04:df:c3:5f:
         94:d5:15:c9:14:41:9c:c4:5d:75:64:15:0d:ff:55:30:ec:86:
         8f:ff:0d:ef:2c:b9:63:46:f6:aa:fc:df:bc:69:fd:2e:12:48:
         64:9a:e0:95:f0:a6:ef:29:8f:01:b1:15:b5:0c:1d:a5:fe:69:
         2c:69:24:78:1e:b3:a7:1c:71:62:ee:ca:c8:97:ac:17:5d:8a:
         c2:f8:47:86:6e:2a:c4:56:31:95:d0:67:89:85:2b:f9:6c:a6:
         5d:46:9d:0c:aa:82:e4:99:51:dd:70:b7:db:56:3d:61:e4:6a:
         e1:5c:d6:f6:fe:3d:de:41:cc:07:ae:63:52:bf:53:53:f4:2b:
         e9:c7:fd:b6:f7:82:5f:85:d2:41:18:db:81:b3:04:1c:c5:1f:
         a4:80:6f:15:20:c9:de:0c:88:0a:1d:d6:66:55:e2:fc:48:c9:
         29:26:69:e0
...
```

Chain in smartphone:

```
################
CERT 1
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            fa:6b:ba:90:4c:26:1d:f2:12:54:f6:7d:cc:de:65:db
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 12 08:19:33 2022 GMT
            Not After : Dec  5 08:19:32 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = www.google.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:bb:86:34:31:51:0f:9b:e3:44:bf:6b:d7:dc:e0:
                    ce:d9:3a:a2:bd:9a:06:46:40:94:e7:06:56:d4:bb:
                    88:a9:ca:22:62:41:9c:23:ea:ac:8f:b9:2a:8d:70:
                    82:49:d4:28:1b:db:43:a8:32:b8:f0:b1:18:8b:0e:
                    1b:18:13:44:7c
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                56:D9:29:89:45:A0:7B:EB:69:6A:77:A4:7B:2B:8C:10:20:1C:FA:FA
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:8A:74:7F:AF:85:CD:EE:95:CD:3D:9C:D0:E2:46:14:F3:71:35:1D:27

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1c3
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.goog/repo/certs/gts1c3.der

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.google.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crls.pki.goog/gts1c3/zdATt0Ex_Fk.crl

            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 51:A3:B0:F5:FD:01:79:9C:56:6D:B8:37:78:8F:0C:A4:
                                7A:CC:1B:27:CB:F7:9E:88:42:9A:0D:FE:D4:8B:05:E5
                    Timestamp : Sep 12 09:19:34.141 2022 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:46:02:21:00:FE:EB:B0:B5:70:5D:B6:55:BA:34:A6:
                                A8:01:97:E0:30:CB:07:48:87:37:0B:46:21:C7:48:E4:
                                B1:21:7F:F3:BF:02:21:00:E4:9C:BF:0D:4B:CA:F9:9A:
                                4B:60:0B:08:AD:C0:6F:A8:06:23:81:F4:6E:B5:0B:BF:
                                11:DF:AF:7B:67:26:F0:E2
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 29:79:BE:F0:9E:39:39:21:F0:56:73:9F:63:A5:77:E5:
                                BE:57:7D:9C:60:0A:F8:F9:4D:5D:26:5C:25:5D:C7:84
                    Timestamp : Sep 12 09:19:34.124 2022 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:44:02:20:37:7B:92:C0:D5:95:F4:59:F0:A3:65:4F:
                                0E:21:39:E8:E1:64:86:C6:7F:61:08:CE:4E:53:CF:0C:
                                92:D9:61:A8:02:20:39:28:8B:C3:14:C5:03:5A:FE:4A:
                                44:1A:EA:28:5B:D9:C1:70:8B:93:6F:87:B7:8B:B7:6E:
                                1E:83:55:E3:71:BE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         64:10:50:5f:86:11:04:34:7f:61:ac:b3:d5:5e:b7:6e:57:12:
         b4:8f:70:30:4f:02:9d:4f:7d:43:e4:ee:9f:09:77:5e:a4:a8:
         c0:34:69:f1:5f:d2:46:c8:b4:82:89:31:55:c6:2e:d8:72:ba:
         10:7a:fe:24:a3:92:d7:4e:75:b9:a3:f1:db:65:30:f4:9f:b2:
         06:96:f6:76:25:0b:8a:58:0b:36:28:f3:83:28:44:bf:7d:b8:
         a8:7e:26:ac:1c:37:a3:e0:30:20:86:f0:f6:2a:24:c9:ab:69:
         97:f7:e1:5c:0f:17:4d:c3:bc:5a:60:03:1d:c0:97:75:b0:37:
         29:c2:3c:78:66:3c:a2:c3:2e:fe:e7:10:5a:c7:74:65:e1:ac:
         48:bc:2b:8e:29:f3:2a:98:a0:06:e4:94:c5:a8:1b:89:3d:93:
         03:22:e3:00:e9:1b:12:b9:5a:0a:12:0e:fc:6c:df:df:0f:81:
         5f:62:d7:a6:bb:9c:53:41:8f:0e:06:44:b9:fe:b8:2b:dc:a4:
         47:fd:d5:d7:c6:d6:7d:70:24:10:cf:82:02:19:f0:26:19:4f:
         45:a1:e3:36:3a:39:2b:66:ad:04:44:1a:db:b9:c4:c6:41:1f:
         b0:27:07:0f:b8:42:ca:a5:da:52:3b:96:3a:f0:5b:10:e8:4d:
         0c:84:bc:96
...

################
CERT 2
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            02:03:bc:53:59:6b:34:c7:18:f5:01:50:66
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 13 00:00:42 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep 30 00:00:42 2027 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:f5:88:df:e7:62:8c:1e:37:f8:37:42:90:7f:6c:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                8A:74:7F:AF:85:CD:EE:95:CD:3D:9C:D0:E2:46:14:F3:71:35:1D:27
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:E4:AF:2B:26:71:1A:2B:48:27:85:2F:52:66:2C:EF:F0:89:13:71:3E

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.pki.goog/gtsr1
                CA Issuers - URI:http://pki.goog/repo/certs/gtsr1.der

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.pki.goog/gtsr1/gtsr1.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.5.3
                  CPS: https://pki.goog/repository/
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         89:7d:ac:20:5c:0c:3c:be:9a:a8:57:95:1b:b4:ae:fa:ab:a5:
         72:71:b4:36:95:fd:df:40:11:03:4c:c2:46:14:bb:14:24:ab:
         f0:50:71:22:db:ad:c4:6e:7f:cf:f1:6a:6f:c8:83:1b:d8:ce:
         89:5f:87:6c:87:b8:a9:0c:a3:9b:a1:62:94:93:95:df:5b:ae:
         66:19:0b:02:96:9e:fc:b5:e7:10:69:3e:7a:cb:46:49:5f:46:
         e1:41:b1:d7:98:4d:65:34:00:80:1a:3f:4f:9f:6c:7f:49:00:
         81:53:41:a4:92:21:82:82:1a:f1:a3:44:5b:2a:50:12:13:4d:
         c1:53:36:f3:42:08:af:54:fa:8e:77:53:1b:64:38:27:17:09:
         bd:58:c9:1b:7c:39:2d:5b:f3:ce:d4:ed:97:db:14:03:bf:09:
         53:24:1f:c2:0c:04:79:98:26:f2:61:f1:53:52:fd:42:8c:1b:
         66:2b:3f:15:a1:bb:ff:f6:9b:e3:81:9a:01:06:71:89:35:28:
         24:dd:e1:bd:eb:19:2d:e1:48:cb:3d:59:83:51:b4:74:c6:9d:
         7c:c6:b1:86:5b:af:cc:34:c4:d3:cc:d4:81:11:95:00:a1:f4:
         12:22:01:fa:b4:83:71:af:8c:b7:8c:73:24:ac:37:53:c2:00:
         90:3f:11:fe:5c:ed:36:94:10:3b:bd:29:ae:e2:c7:3a:62:3b:
         6c:63:d9:80:bf:59:71:ac:63:27:b9:4c:17:a0:da:f6:73:15:
         bf:2a:de:8f:f3:a5:6c:32:81:33:03:d0:86:51:71:99:34:ba:
         93:8d:5d:b5:51:58:f7:b2:93:e8:01:f6:59:be:71:9b:fd:4d:
         28:ce:cf:6d:c7:16:dc:f7:d1:d6:46:9b:a7:ca:6b:e9:77:0f:
         fd:a0:b6:1b:23:83:1d:10:1a:d9:09:00:84:e0:44:d3:a2:75:
         23:b3:34:86:f6:20:b0:a4:5e:10:1d:e0:52:46:00:9d:b1:0f:
         1f:21:70:51:f5:9a:dd:06:fc:55:f4:2b:0e:33:77:c3:4b:42:
         c2:f1:77:13:fc:73:80:94:eb:1f:bb:37:3f:ce:02:2a:66:b0:
         73:1d:32:a5:32:6c:32:b0:8e:e0:c4:23:ff:5b:7d:4d:65:70:
         ac:2b:9b:3d:ce:db:e0:6d:8e:32:80:be:96:9f:92:63:bc:97:
         bb:5d:b9:f4:e1:71:5e:2a:e4:ef:03:22:b1:8a:65:3a:8f:c0:
         93:65:d4:85:cd:0f:0f:5b:83:59:16:47:16:2d:9c:24:3a:c8:
         80:a6:26:14:85:9b:f6:37:9b:ac:6f:f9:c5:c3:06:51:f3:e2:
         7f:c5:b1:10:ba:51:f4:dd
...


################
CERT 3
################

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            6e:47:a9:c5:4b:47:0c:0d:ec:33:d0:89:b9:1c:f4:e1
        Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 22 00:00:00 2016 GMT
            Not After : Jun 22 00:00:00 2036 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b6:11:02:8b:1e:e3:a1:77:9b:3b:dc:bf:94:3e:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E4:AF:2B:26:71:1A:2B:48:27:85:2F:52:66:2C:EF:F0:89:13:71:3E
    Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
         38:96:0a:ee:3d:b4:96:1e:5f:ef:9d:9c:0b:33:9f:2b:e0:ca:
         fd:d2:8e:0a:1f:41:74:a5:7c:aa:84:d4:e5:f2:1e:e6:37:52:
         32:9c:0b:d1:61:1d:bf:28:c1:b6:44:29:35:75:77:98:b2:7c:
         d9:bd:74:ac:8a:68:e3:a9:31:09:29:01:60:73:e3:47:7c:53:
         a8:90:4a:27:ef:4b:d7:9f:93:e7:82:36:ce:9a:68:0c:82:e7:
         cf:d4:10:16:6f:5f:0e:99:5c:f6:1f:71:7d:ef:ef:7b:2f:7e:
         ea:36:d6:97:70:0b:15:ee:d7:5c:56:6a:33:a5:e3:49:38:0c:
         b8:7d:fb:8d:85:a4:b1:59:5e:f4:6a:e1:dd:a1:f6:64:44:ae:
         e6:51:83:21:66:c6:11:3e:f3:ce:47:ee:9c:28:1f:25:da:ff:
         ac:66:95:dd:35:0f:5c:ef:20:2c:62:fd:91:ba:a9:cc:fc:5a:
         9c:93:81:83:29:97:4a:7c:5a:72:b4:39:d0:b7:77:cb:79:fd:
         69:3a:92:37:ed:6e:38:65:46:7e:e9:60:bd:79:88:97:5f:38:
         12:f4:ee:af:5b:82:c8:86:d5:e1:99:6d:8c:04:f2:76:ba:49:
         f6:6e:e9:6d:1e:5f:a0:ef:27:82:76:40:f8:a6:d3:58:5c:0f:
         2c:42:da:42:c6:7b:88:34:c7:c1:d8:45:9b:c1:3e:c5:61:1d:
         d9:63:50:49:f6:34:85:6a:e0:18:c5:6e:47:ab:41:42:29:9b:
         f6:60:0d:d2:31:d3:63:98:23:93:5a:00:81:48:b4:ef:cd:8a:
         cd:c9:cf:99:ee:d9:9e:aa:36:e1:68:4b:71:49:14:36:28:3a:
         3d:1d:ce:9a:8f:25:e6:80:71:61:2b:b5:7b:cc:f9:25:16:81:
         e1:31:5f:a1:a3:7e:16:a4:9c:16:6a:97:18:bd:76:72:a5:0b:
         9e:1d:36:e6:2f:a1:2f:be:70:91:0f:a8:e6:da:f8:c4:92:40:
         6c:25:7e:7b:b3:09:dc:b2:17:ad:80:44:f0:68:a5:8f:94:75:
         ff:74:5a:e8:a8:02:7c:0c:09:e2:a9:4b:0b:a0:85:0b:62:b9:
         ef:a1:31:92:fb:ef:f6:51:04:89:6c:e8:a9:74:a1:bb:17:b3:
         b5:fd:49:0f:7c:3c:ec:83:18:20:43:4e:d5:93:ba:b4:34:b1:
         1f:16:36:1f:0c:e6:64:39:16:4c:dc:e0:fe:1d:c8:a9:62:3d:
         40:ea:ca:c5:34:02:b4:ae:89:88:33:35:dc:2c:13:73:d8:27:
         f1:d0:72:ee:75:3b:22:de:98:68:66:5b:f1:c6:63:47:55:1c:
         ba:a5:08:51:75:a6:48:25
...
```

A few things to notice:

- CERT 2 coincides (GTS CA 1C3), the rest do not.
- In smartphone CERT 1 CN field it shows [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) while in desktop CERT 1 CN field it shows *.google.com. Is this enough to explain the differences in other fields and in the hashes? I typed the same urls in both devices and then obtained the certificates: in desktop downdloaded from firefox interface, in smartphone downloaded through TLS Inspector APP (Apple Store app).
- I was able to find CERT 1 and CERT 2 from desktop in crt.sh but not CERT 1 from smartphone.
- When I run `openssl verify -CAfile cert2smartphone.pem -untrusted cert1smartphone.pem cert1smartphone.pem` I get OK. So it seems the certificate is well-formed and matches the trusted intermediate authority (GTS CA 1C3). Is this enough for me to trust CERT 1 from smartphone?

Should I be concerned about some type of MITM or fraud related to this certificate chain in my smartphone? Can I trust these certificates?

Thanks.

---

Edit, output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443`:

```
Server certificate
subject=CN = www.google.com

issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4295 bytes and written 386 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read:errno=0
```

Comment: I see the _precert_ for your smartphone cert https://crt.sh/?id=7524181547 but not the actual cert (I had to 'fix' the serial, which is DER/BER-encoded as negative, by prefixing 00). This suggests you are getting a server (or 'personality') that isn't accessed much. Could the smartphone be using IPv6 and the desktop v4, or maybe something unusual for DNS? (Your _desktop_ case cert with lots of SANs _might_ occur if you didn't send SNI, but firefox definitely should do so.)

Comment: What is a precert? What is the relationship between the cert and the precert? The smartphone is not using IPv6, that I am aware of. The DNS are both configured automatically, two IPs each, coinciding in both devices; I checked in via who.is and apps.db.ripe.net in turn and they seem legitimate (IPs assigned to my ISP). What should I do regarding the lots of SAN, I am using firefox. I am checking the names in who.is and not sure if it is suspicious.

Comment: https://certificate.transparency.dev/howctworks/#stepby . On further thought, IME Firefox at least on Windows prefers IPv6, so that might differ -- although I'm surprised a supported iPhone doesn't do v6. Plus google has many servers and uses short TTLs, so even if both your clients used the same DNS servers but made requests a few minutes apart, possibly even less than a minute, they could get different servers and different certs. The many SANs in 26:3e:... do look like google properties to me, plus the cert does validate, it's just surprising to get that when using SNI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing different certificate chains on the two devices is because [GTS Root R1 is cross-signed](https://security.googleblog.com/2021/03/google-https-and-device-compatibility.html).

In other words, Google has two different versions of its GTS Root R1 certificate.

If you look at GTS Root R1 in your certificate chain on your smartphone, you’ll notice that it is self-signed.  Therefore, devices (like your smartphone) that have GTS Root R1 installed in the trust store will recognize GTS Root R1 as a root certificate, and build a certificate chain that chains-up to GTS Root R1.  Not surprisingly, this is the chain that the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) serves.

On the other hand, if you look at GTS Root R1 in your certificate chain on your desktop computer, you’ll notice that it is signed by GlobalSign's root certificate GlobalSign Root CA.  Devices (like your desktop computer) that have GlobalSign Root CA installed in their trust store but do not have GTS Root R1 in their trust store will build a certificate chain that chains-up to GlobalSign Root CA.

Both versions of GTS Root R1 have the same subject name and the same public key.  However, one is self-signed, and the other is signed by a different root certificate.  This is cross-signing.

By cross-signing GTS Root R1, Google is able to increase the trust in GTS Root R1, as GTS Root R1 is trusted by newer devices that have GTS Root R1 installed in their trust store, as well as older devices that have GlobalSign Root CA installed in their trust store.

This works, because - if the chain served by the server chains-up to a root certificate that is not in the device's trust store, then the browser will try to build a different chain that does chain-up to a root certificate in the trust store.  See [What could cause classic "ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID" when I can confirm no error from numerous other clients?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258190/what-could-cause-classic-err-cert-date-invalid-when-i-can-confirm-no-error-fro) for more info.

---

Added 10/9/2022 in response to OP's questions in the comments about verifying certificates manually using openssl.

You can use this procedure to verify the certificate chain manually using openssl:

```
#Download the leaf certificate for www.google.com and save to leaf.pem
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | openssl x509 > leaf.pem

#view info about leaf.pem
cat leaf.pem | openssl x509 -text

#in my case, the subject CN is www.gooogle.com and the issuer CN is GTS CA 1C3 (your may be different)

#download the issuer cert GTS CA 1C3 from Google's certificate repository at https://pki.goog/repository/:
wget https://pki.goog/repo/certs/gts1c3.pem

#verify that leaf.crt is signed by GTS CA 1C3
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile gts1c3.pem leaf.pem

#should return leaf.pem: OK
```

You can repeat the same procedure to verify the signatures up the chain, until you reach the root certificate.

---

Added 10/10/2022 in response to further comments:

It seems that [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) serves different leaf certificates depending on the IP address that your DNS resolves [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) to.  Perhaps your smartphone is resolving [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) to a different IP address than your desktop computer is.  In any case, after a little poking around, I found that 142.250.65.196 returns the leaf certificate for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) that you are seeing on your smartphone.  Using the following command, you can download this leaf certificate to your system:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect 142.250.65.196:443  -servername www.google.com | openssl x509 > leaf.pem
```

Then, use the following command to view information about this certificate:

```
cat leaf.pem | openssl x509 -text
```

As you can see, the public key, subject, issuer, validity dates, etc. all match what you posted.

Now, we can verify the signature by GTS CA 1C3 on the certificate:

```
wget https://pki.goog/repo/certs/gts1c3.pem
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile gts1c3.pem leaf.pem
```

As hoped, the signature is valid.  This is a strong indication that the leaf certificate that you are seeing on your smartphone is authentic.  Otherwise, an attacker would have had to have access to the private key for GTS CA 1C3 in order to have created the signature by GTS CA 1C3 on this leaf certificate.

Comment: Many thanks, I hadn't considered this information. I think this explains the discrepancies in the root certificates. However, what about the leaf? Please, could you address the questions I made a little bit more specifically? In particular, is it normal not being able to find the leaf in crt.sh? Also, should the openssl verify check I made be enough to trust?

Comment: @JoD I'm glad this helped.  Google has many leaf certificates.  What's important is that the leaf certificate that it serves you chains-up to a root certificate that your device trusts.  I'm not sure how your system created crt.sh, so I can't comment on why the leaf cert is not included in it.  If you do `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443`, this will show you the complete certificate chain and verify all of the signatures in the chain.

Comment: @JoD  I added a bit at the end of my answer about how to verify the certificate chain manually using openssl.

Comment: mti: `https://crt.sh` is a transparency-log viewer and search tool run by Sectigo-formerly-Comodo. Google is a big supporter of CT and IINM by policy all Google certs should be logged.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by crt.sh, sorry for not specifying the https://. Thanks for the comments/additions. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @mti2935 I edited the post with the output of the ```openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443```. Only the last lines since the post is already too long, I think these are the important ones.

Comment: @JoD,  Please see what I added to my answer a few moments ago regarding your concern about the authenticity of the leaf certificate for www.google.com that you are seeing on your smartphone.